# Replace the last word in query string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My sql string is

```
SELECT '1' + char(10) + '2' + char(10)
```

I want to replace the last char(10) by '' 
but how ???

Comment: why you add CHAR(10) at the end if you want remove it?

Comment: y not jus `SELECT '1' + char(10) + '2' + char(10)+'"'`

Comment: joe it just a simple exemple of my work

Answer (score 1):

If `char(10)` is always the last character simply chop it off:

```
 SET MyString = LEFT(MyString, LEN(MyString) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
SELECT '1' + char(10) + '2"'
```